# Php GD add text to png image always follow image background color

Tags: php, image, png, gd

When adding text to a png image using gd library the text always follows the image background color even I have set the color using the `imagecolorallocate()`, why is this?

This is my code:

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');

$im = imagecreatefrompng('picture.png');

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
$text = 'A Simple Text String';
$font_path = './font/arial.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 16, 0, 100, 200, $text_color, $font_path, $text);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: I think my code has no problem, but the image itself. I try others image, it works perfectly. Does any one know why is the problem when I create the png image? I need some advice and suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the problem PNG to your question? I've run your code as-is and I end up with the text drawn in the colour specified in the code.

Comment: @timclutton You mean this -> "Php GD add text to png image always follow image background color"? I think the PNG already in the question. Yup, I just tried with others png image, it works perfectly. But don't know why my own created image causing this problem. May be I created the png image in wrong way. T.T

Comment: I mean, can you upload the image that you are having a problem with and embed it in your question so that we test with it. I can run the code perfectly with my test image, and you say it works with other images.  So it must be a problem with that exact image file.

Comment: Could it be a problem when the image is indexed color, and this background color is not in the palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading an 8-bit PNG file, chances are that all 256 entries in the color palette have already been allocated. Your call to imagecolorallocate() will return false. That gets converted to 0, which presumably is the index of the background color.

What you should do is call imagecolorstotal() to see if it's less than 256. If the palette is full, convert the image to true color before proceeding.

Comment: Yup, thank you a lot. You have solved my problem. If I create a bigger bit PNG will it still have this problem?